# How to join the Monero Slack?

Tags: monero-community

I figured out the website is https://monero.slack.com. Signing up isn't very obvious for me. On the home page, it says something about "find your team". How does this all work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PM [u/needmoney90](https://www.reddit.com/user/needmoney90) or [u/SamsungGalaxyPlayer](https://www.reddit.com/user/SamsungGalaxyPlayer) on Reddit with your e-mail address, or ping them on IRC.